# pm2 deploy [node.js] - Hide Credentials and Sensitive Data

Tags: node.js, git, credentials, password-protection, pm2

My goal is to hide credentials from my git repo. 
My entire application pipeline uses Jenkins MultiBranch + PM2 with deploy functionality.

The below sample app works fine, it deploys with pm2, no issues with the functionality, just with the security.

However, as you can see the environment variables are being set with the password in them.

PM2's native workflow pulls from git at execution. So I need to somehow hold my credentials securely in git, or have them sit outside my repo, but having any files outside the repo can get lost and forgotten across deployment nodes.

Normally I would just write the password hard coded into a config file, however that means the config file would either have to be completely isolated from the repo (not good, could easily get lost/forgotten) or password is put into the config file and checked in (same issue I'm having now).

Another idea is to keep a "template" config file in the repo, then fill it out on the deployment server only. That would work fine, however upon next execution, pm2 will pull down the repo, overwriting my version with the git version.

So with all that said - I'm a bit at a loss on how to do this.

BEST CASE scenario I could put the creds into Jenkins credential manager which is passed at build time. However since it's not Jenkins actually doing the deployment (pm2 is doing it) I feel this wouldn't be possible.

**I'm looking for ideas and best practices to get around this conundrum.**  How do you handle this in your apps?

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "myapp",
    "script"      : "myapp.js",
    "version"     : "0.0.1",
    "watch"       : true,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "env_production" : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production",
       "PORT": 3009,
       "DB_HOST":"proddb.example.com",
       "DB_PASS":"db_password"
    },
    "env_stage" : {
       "NODE_ENV": "stage",
       "PORT": 3009,
       "DB_HOST":"stagedb.example.com",
       "DB_PASS":"db_password"
    }
  }],
  "deploy" : {
    "stage" : {
      "user" : "pm2deploy",
      "host" : "node01stage.example.com",
      "ref"  : "origin/stage",
      "repo" : "git@example.com:devproj/myapp.git",
      "path" : "/var/www",
      "post-deploy" : ". ~/.bash_profile && npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env stage"
    },
    "production" : {
      "user" : "pm2deploy",
      "host" : "node01prod.example.com",
      "ref"  : "origin/master",
      "repo" : "git@example.com:devproj/myapp.git",
      "path" : "/var/www",
      "post-deploy" : ". ~/.bash_profile && npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @BalasubramaniM we just decided to not use the `pm2 deploy` functionality and deploy apps through another method. Our experience with `pm2 deploy` proved it wasn't quite stable or active enough to warrant production use.

Comment: It would be helpful if you wish to share your another method here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or similar to keep your sensitive data away from pm2 config and use `env` attribute for you `deploy.production` configuration to enject ENV vars into remote execution.

From [pm2 docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/):

```
// Environment variables that must be injected in all applications on this env
"env"  : {
  "NODE_ENV": "production"
}
```

Example setup:

*.env:*

```
DB_HOST=proddb.example.com
DB_PASS=db_password
```

*ecosystem.config.js:*

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "myapp",
    "script"      : "myapp.js",
    "version"     : "0.0.1",
    "watch"       : true,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "env_production" : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production",
       "PORT": 3009,
    },
    "env_stage" : {
       "NODE_ENV": "stage",
       "PORT": 3009,
    }
  }],
  "deploy" : {
    "stage" : {
      "user" : "pm2deploy",
      "host" : "node01stage.example.com",
      "ref"  : "origin/stage",
      "repo" : "git@example.com:devproj/myapp.git",
      "path" : "/var/www",
      "post-deploy" : ". ~/.bash_profile && npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env stage"
    },
    "production" : {
      "user" : "pm2deploy",
      "host" : "node01prod.example.com",
      "ref"  : "origin/master",
      "repo" : "git@example.com:devproj/myapp.git",
      "path" : "/var/www",
      "post-deploy" : ". ~/.bash_profile && npm install && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.json --env production",
      "env": {
        DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST,
        DB_PASS: process.env.DB_PASS,
      },
    }
  }
};
```

.env should be added to `.gitignore`, so that your sensitive data is never checked in.